# Impossible to change gitlab project url

Tags: nginx, gitlab, centos6

I downloaded rpm installer for Centos and installed gitlab.
I also fallowed this link: [How to change URL of a working GitLab install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19456129/how-to-change-url-of-a-working-gitlab-install)

I searched for 'how to change gitlab url' and similar... but found old results point to /etc/nginx/sites-enabled. But there is no directories like that. I changed every Url I found in files but still project url is the old. Is there any way to change it directly in template files or in config ? Tnx in advance

Comment: @omeinusch I also seen that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just edited this file:
'/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config/gitlab.yml' and now it is file :)