# Gitlab is starting from any url, not just the one specified in conf file

Tags: git, ubuntu, ssh, gitlab

I have just installed gitlab on my website using the omnibus package.
I am running ubuntu 14.04.

Gitlab would launch on any url of my website : myProviderUrl.com, myDomain.com and gitlab.myDomain.com

myDomain.com and gitlab.myDomain.com are virtual host configured with apache and they are working successfully when gitlab is not running. The point to different folders on my VPS.

When I do : `sudo nano /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`

I have the following line :

> external_url: 'http://gitlab.myDomain.com'

When I do : `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure`
The configuration is cascaded correclty to every other conf file and in any of the files I have the same gitlab.myDomain.com url.

the files I checked :

> config/gitlab.yml and gitlab-shell/config.yml

in lib/support/nginx/gitlab, I also have the good url and I have tried successively to uncomment the listen, with no result : gitlab still launches from any url of my website.

```
server {
  listen 0.0.0.0:80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;
  server_name gitlab.myDomain.com; ## Replace this with something like gitlab.example.com
  server_tokens off; ## Don't show the nginx version number, a security best practice
  root /home/git/gitlab/public;
}
```

What can I do ? Any idea of things I could test or modify ? THanks a lot!

Comment: See if this post helps: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19456129/1144203

Comment: well, after following those steps, gitlab is still launching from either mysite.com or www.mysite.com or my IP but not from gitlab.mysite.com. I'm a newbie on linux so I'm not sure I have the right subdomain configuration for this to work. I've only put the 127.0.0.1 gitlab.mysite.com gitlab in /etc/hosts

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you met here might be that you haven't set the web server (reverse proxy server) correctly.

Which web server do you use for your `gitlab` server?

Take `nginx` as an example, in the `nginx` configure file for `gitlab`, you should set the `server_name` as your expected domain `gitlab.mysite.com`, such as:

```
server {
  listen 0.0.0.0:80 default_server;
  #listen [::]:80 default_server;
  server_name gitlab.mysite.com; ## Replace this with something like gitlab.example.
com
  ...
}
```

Comment: hmmm, I don't follow you very well. I want gitlab to be available at the gitlab.mysite.com url. And you say I should use another url for the server name? any url?

Comment: Is this not working because maybe nginx is replacing apache as a webserver?

Comment: @SébastienVassaux I mean the problem you met was decided by the configuration of your web server (apache, nginx, or any others you used). So you'd better check that part. But I cannot tell what's the exact problem for now.