# Gitlab - project path hash breaks cloning and CI

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm currently setting up gitlab and loving it so far. I'm currently trying to setup CI using the gitlab runner, which is working great, except for the point when it tries to clone the repo, see image:

[image: Gitlab Runner]

It's trying to pull the repo from a "hash" where it should be using an IP address. I'm not sure why this is the case, but every project I create uses a hash in the project path and not the address, for example:

[image]

Essentially I would like to revert the project paths to the actual hostname / IP, I can't see a configuration option for this, although maybe I'm missing the point here?

Comment: Your images are not showing up.

Comment: Strange, I can see them, anyway, the image shows the CI failing the checkout:

**fatal: unable to access 'http://gitlab-ci-token:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@39axxxxxe9b0/will/CI-Testing.git/': Couldn't resolve host '39axxxxxe9b0'**

And the project URL is similar: 

**http://will@39axxxxxe9b0/will/CI-xxxxx.git**

Where I would expect the hostname / IP instead of the hash starting with 39

Comment: The images are showing fine, maybe your proxy blocks `imgur.com` @TimBiegeleisen? @Xerphiel please do not embed textual output via images though, but directly in the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change URL of a working GitLab install?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19456129/how-to-change-url-of-a-working-gitlab-install)

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate, I want to understand why the project path shows as an IP when I create the project, but is immediately hashed once the project is created, opposed to remaining as an IP / host name.

Comment: If you change the `external_url` parameter in the gitlab configuration file and run `gitlab-ctl reconfigure` and maybe `gitlab-ctl restart`, it should update all the links for all the projects. By default, when you install gitlab, it will set the `external_url` to the machine's hostname. If you're running gitlab inside docker, that hostname will look like a hash of some sort.